# Cumulative sum of a group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table that have just 2 columns month and sales, and I am trying to first sum the sales and group by month and next to it have a cumulative sum of the column sales, but I am getting an error in my SQL

With this query I can group by month and get the sum of sales by month

```
select month, sum(sales)
from sales
group by month
```

and with this query I can get the cumulative sum but is not grouped by month

```
select month
    , sum(sales) over(order by month) as cum_sum
from sales
```

Now how can I combine those 2 in 1 select statement that works?

So for this table

```
month   sales
1   100
1   200
2   100
2   100
3   100
3   50
```

I would get this result

```
month month_sales    cum_sum
1         300          300
2         200          500
3         150          650
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine it like this

```
select month, 
       sum(sales) as month_sales,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (order by month)     as cum_sum
from   sales
group by month
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4abec8476c45261dfd749fc544fdd17)

Note : this works for `SQL Server` and `MySQL`. Tested on fiddle

Comment: An excellent demonstration of window functions over aggregate functions on the same level. By the way `min(sum(sales)) over (partition by month)` might as well be just `sum(sales)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d0e93b5a177aaeda061a2bad181fd0e

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right. Must be too much caffeine this morning. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can try to use a subquery to calculate total sales each month before `sum` window function.

```
SELECT t1.*,sum(total_sales) over(order by month) as cum_sum
FROM (
  select month, sum(sales) total_sales
  from sales
  group by month
) t1
```